# Postgresql large database dump

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, pg-dump

I have a postgresql database stored on a remote machine accessible via ssh. Due to space issues, I am unable to store the backup (pg_dump) on the remote server, I was wondering if I could save it on my local machine directly?

Comment: Simply use `pg_dump` by specifying a remote host like `sudo -u postgres pg_dump -a -h remote_host -p remote_psql_port -U postgres -d db_name > path_to_store_backup.sql`

Comment: pg_dump is a _client_ application you can run it on any computer that can connect to your database server